# reading an array

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsarray

I create random numbers using the following code and store them in an array.

```
NSMutableSet *aSet = [NSMutableSet setWithCapacity:6];

while([aSet count]<=6){

    int Randnum = arc4random() % 12;

    [aSet addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:Randnum]];
} 

NSArray *arrayOfUniqueRandomNumbers = [aSet allObjects];
```

Now, I need to read the array to get the values one-by-one using a forloop like

```
for (int i = 0; i<6; i++);
```

Can anyone please help me to finish the code?

Comment: You have only 6 random numbers, apparently; you need not use NSMutableSet and them read it into an NSArray - just directly use NSArray to store the 6 values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
for (NSNumber *val in arrayOfUniqueRandomNumbers) {
    int i = [val intValue];
    ...
}
```